# Relating the signs of $f$, $f'$ and $f''$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function such that $f$ and $f'$ are differentiable for all $x$. If $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x\ge 0$ and $f''(x)\lt 0$ for all $x\ge 0$, prove that $f'(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Suppose there were an $y$ with $f'(y) < 0$. What can you say about $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ for $x > y$?

Comment: I don't know...maybe $f'(x)\lt f'(y)\lt 0$ and then $f(x)\lt f(y)$

Comment: Right. Actually, $f'(x) \leqslant f'(y)$ is enough. You can say more than just $f(x) < f(y)$, you can say by how much at least.

Comment: sorry, I tried and I still cannot prove it. could you give me more hits?

Comment: Suppose you had $f'(x) = f'(y)$ for all $x > y$. Write $f(x)$ in terms of $f(y)$, $f'(y)$ and $(x-y)$. Now, what can change when not $f'(x) = f'(y)$ but $f'(x) < f'(y)$?

Comment: so $f(x)-f(y)=f'(y)(x-y)$ and if $f'(x)\lt f'(y)$, then $f'(x) \lt \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ and since $f(x)\lt f(y)$ and $x>y$, then $f'(x)<0$ ?

Comment: That $f'(x) < 0$, you know from our assumption. You need to see that then $f(x) < 0$ for large enough $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x_0)=a<0$, for some $a\ge 0$, the for all $x\ge x_0$:
$$
f'(x)-f'(x_0)=(x-x_0)f''(\eta), \,\,\text{for some $\eta\in(x_0,x)$},
$$
and thus
$$
f'(x)\lt f'(x_0)\,\,\,\text{for all $x\ge x_0$}.
$$
Thus
$$
f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x f'(t)\,dt \le f(x_0)+a(x-x_0).
$$
But $f(x_0)+a(x-x_0)\to -\infty$, as $x\to\infty$, and hence $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$,
which contradicts the fact that $f(x)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f''(x)\le 0$ so that $f$ is concave.  If $f'(a)<0$ somewhere, then (since $f$ is concave) its graph is below the tangent line at $a$, and therefore $f$ is eventually negative.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $f'(a) < 0$ for some $a \geq 0$. Then since $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x \geq 0$, it follows that $f'(x) < f'(a) < 0$ for all $x > a$. It follows that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing in $[a, \infty)$ and since $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a, \infty)$, it follows that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = A$ exists and $A \geq 0$.

Next we can see that $f''(x) < 0$ so that $f'(x)$ is strictly decreasing for all $x$ and hence either $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) = B$ or $f'(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. In the first case if $B$ exists then we must have $B \leq f'(a) < 0$ (because $f'(x) < f'(a)$ for all $x \in (a, \infty)$). By Mean Value theorem we have $f(x) - f(x/2) = (x/2)f'(c)$ for some $c$ satisfying $x/2 < c < x$. Taking limits as $x \to \infty$ we get a contradiction as LHS tends to $A - A = 0$ and RHS diverges to $-\infty$ because $f'(c)$ tends to a negative value. Same contradiction holds if $f'(x) \to -\infty$.

It follows that our assumption of existence of $a$ with $f'(a) < 0$ is wrong. Thus $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.

**Update**: From the above proof it is easy to see that the result in question is true even if we assume $f(x) > K$ for some constant $K$. It is not necessary for $f(x)$ to be positive (like in the original question), it just needs to be bounded below.